# Shrinkwrap modifier decal - When I join with object disappears

Tags: modeling, texturing, objects, shrinkwrap

I have made a decal and added a shrinkwrap modifier with the following settings.
[image]

However when I apply the modifier to the decal and apply all scale, rotation, and position to both the decal and the object I want to attach the decal to and they to join them. The decal disappears. I believe it has something to do with the origin of either the object or the decal.  Since when I change it the invisible decal changes position.

[image]

How can I fix this?
file uploaded here [enter link description here](https://pasteall.org/media/c/3/c3e79fe746656480dd638ba384694264.blend)

Comment: Since the decal is 2d, it's not just Z fighting the surface?? Maybe you can share your .blend so we can have a look? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I uploaded the file here is the link.  https://pasteall.org/media/c/3/c3e79fe746656480dd638ba384694264.blend

Comment: I missed this when I first read your question, you say "and they to join them" Are you trying to join the 2 objects together into 1 object?

Comment: Yes I am trying to join the decal with the building.   Sorry for the miss type.

Comment: When you join them, basically the object with the decal is deleted, so it's material is removed. You would need to add the material to the building object and assign it to the appropriate faces.